# how to read from file and display the data in desired rows in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file

I am trying to read from a file and display the data in rows 6, 11, 111 and 127 in Matlab. I could not figure out how to do it. I have been searching Matlab forums and this platform for an answer. I used fscanf, textscan and other functions but they did not work as intended. I also used a for loop but again the output was not what I wanted. I can now only read one row and display it. Simply I want to display all of them(data in rows given above) at the same time. How can I do that?

matlab code

```
n = [0 :1: 127];

%% Problem 1
figure
x1 = cos(0.17*pi*n)
%it creates file and writes content of x1 to the file
fileID = fopen('file.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID,'%d \n',x1);
fclose(fileID);
%line number can be changed in order to obtain wanted values. 
fileID = fopen('file.txt');
line = 6;
C = textscan(fileID,'%s',1,'delimiter','\n', 'headerlines',line-1);
celldisp(C)
fclose(fileID);
```

and this is the file

```
1 
8.607420e-01 
4.817537e-01 
-3.141076e-02 
-5.358268e-01 
-8.910065e-01 
-9.980267e-01 
-8.270806e-01 
-4.257793e-01 
9.410831e-02 
5.877853e-01 
9.177546e-01 
9.921147e-01 
7.901550e-01 
3.681246e-01 
-1.564345e-01 
-6.374240e-01 
-9.408808e-01 
-9.822873e-01 
-7.501111e-01 
-3.090170e-01 
2.181432e-01 
6.845471e-01 
9.602937e-01 
9.685832e-01 
7.071068e-01 
2.486899e-01 
-2.789911e-01 
-7.289686e-01 
-9.759168e-01 
-9.510565e-01 
-6.613119e-01 
-1.873813e-01 
3.387379e-01 
7.705132e-01 
9.876883e-01 
9.297765e-01 
6.129071e-01 
1.253332e-01 
-3.971479e-01 
-8.090170e-01 
-9.955620e-01 
-9.048271e-01 
-5.620834e-01 
-6.279052e-02 
4.539905e-01 
8.443279e-01 
9.995066e-01 
8.763067e-01 
5.090414e-01 
-4.288121e-15 
-5.090414e-01 
-8.763067e-01 
-9.995066e-01 
-8.443279e-01 
-4.539905e-01 
6.279052e-02 
5.620834e-01 
9.048271e-01 
9.955620e-01 
8.090170e-01 
3.971479e-01 
-1.253332e-01 
-6.129071e-01 
-9.297765e-01 
-9.876883e-01 
-7.705132e-01 
-3.387379e-01 
1.873813e-01 
6.613119e-01 
9.510565e-01 
9.759168e-01 
7.289686e-01 
2.789911e-01 
-2.486899e-01 
-7.071068e-01 
-9.685832e-01 
-9.602937e-01 
-6.845471e-01 
-2.181432e-01 
3.090170e-01 
7.501111e-01 
9.822873e-01 
9.408808e-01 
6.374240e-01 
1.564345e-01 
-3.681246e-01 
-7.901550e-01 
-9.921147e-01 
-9.177546e-01 
-5.877853e-01 
-9.410831e-02 
4.257793e-01 
8.270806e-01 
9.980267e-01 
8.910065e-01 
5.358268e-01 
3.141076e-02 
-4.817537e-01 
-8.607420e-01 
-1 
-8.607420e-01 
-4.817537e-01 
3.141076e-02 
5.358268e-01 
8.910065e-01 
9.980267e-01 
8.270806e-01 
4.257793e-01 
-9.410831e-02 
-5.877853e-01 
-9.177546e-01 
-9.921147e-01 
-7.901550e-01 
-3.681246e-01 
1.564345e-01 
6.374240e-01 
9.408808e-01 
9.822873e-01 
7.501111e-01 
3.090170e-01 
-2.181432e-01 
-6.845471e-01 
-9.602937e-01 
-9.685832e-01 
-7.071068e-01 
-2.486899e-01 
2.789911e-01
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: I am posting the code here right now

Comment: Please also add a sample of the file you're trying to read.

Comment: I did as you wished

Comment: How is the output form a for loop is not what you wanted?

Comment: There might be other ways to achieve the same result but our teacher wants us to read several row or lines of data from the file and display them. In my case there are 4 rows that is expected to be red and displayed. For loop or any other loop or if statements that might help is acceptable in the sake of achievement of the task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the file is not exceedingly large, the simplest way would probably be read the entire file & index the output to your desired lines.

```
line = [6 11 111 127];
fileID = fopen('file.txt');
C = textscan(fileID,'%s','delimiter','\n');
fclose(fileID);
disp(C{1}(line))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I appreciate your effort.